# Static Single Assignment: not all possible paths define a variable - how to insert PHI?

Tags: compiler-construction, ssa

I am implementing *SSA construction* for a compiler I'm writing. There is something I don't understand in the SSA algorithms (using [the Cytron paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=115320) and the book *Modern Compiler Implementation in Java, second edition* by A.W. Appel). What if a variable `y` is defined for the first time (and used) in one straight control flow path but never defined in another parallel path. Do I have to insert a PHI-function at the join point (the dominance frontier of the block defining `y`)?

```
x = 1;            // A
if (P)            // A
    y = x + 1;    // B
    y = y + 1;    // B
x = x + 1;        // C
return;           // C
```

For example, in block B there is the first definition of `y`. Do I have to insert a PHI instruction at the start of block C, with two operands (one for each incoming control flow path)? Then on SSA renaming: how would I name the operand coming from the path `A -> C` (not through B) where `y` is never defined?

```
Entry --- A --------- C --- Exit
           \         /
            \-- B --/
```

Comment: No, if the variable never escapes the block where it is defined, then you don't need a phi-function. I dont understand why you think you need one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading through the materials again, I found a small hint in the book *Modern Compiler Implementation in Java, second edition* by A.W. Appel about an implicit definition of a variable `c0`. Further searching uncovered that the algorithms expect that all variables have an implicit definition just before the first basic block. This implicit definition represents the fact that the variable is global, a parameter or an uninitialized variable.

Adding this implicit definition solves my problem, and the example would become:

```
x1 = 1;           // A
if (P)            // A
    y1 = x1 + 1;  // B
    y2 = y1 + 1;  // B
y3 = φ(y0, y2)    // C
x2 = x1 + 1;      // C
return;           // C
```

Comment: I am also trying to implement SSA, and following the 'Modern Compiler Implementation in Java, second edition by A.W' book I don't understand if i do y3 = φ(y0, y2) , where do I define  φ and how? if you can give some hint it will be really helpful. thank you.